# How can I do React navigation user actions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

My English is not good, I apologize in advance. I am using React native tab menu. But user login and profile sections appear at the same time. For this, I hide it if there is a token. But when I steer, my profile does not appear. It only appears when I click on another tab. I guess it doesn't appear instantly because it waits with await.

```
let token = null;

export default function BottomTabNavigator({ navigation, route }) {
  navigation.setOptions({ headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route) });  
  _getToken();

  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator initialRouteName={INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME}>
      {token ?
        <BottomTab.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={ProfileScreen}        
          options={{
            title: 'Profilim',
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="md-person" />,
          }}
        /> 
      : <BottomTab.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={LoginScreen}        
          options={{
            title: 'Giriş Yap',
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="md-person" />,
          }}
        />}     
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}

async function _getToken() {  
  try {
    token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Cant you just use https://reactnavigation.org/ ?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow I have read the documentation, but my standards are different from those in the example.

Comment: hey @Dodiş, the problem is token is not updated so it is not updating the screen as you login in.
In simple terms, think of it like this when you log in you store the token but react is not yet aware if local storage is updated or not. One simple way is to extract the screen around a wrapper like ProtectedRoutes which will only render the routes which require the token.

Comment: hey @LalitYadav, thanks your answer, Can you show me a little example? :)

Comment: sure @Dodiş, this is a very simple demonstration but this is essentially how you can buildup upon check this gist https://gist.github.com/therise3107/bd390702bf3ec1210526e2d62391987a